# How can I make GetFiles() exclude files with extensions that start with the search extension?

Tags: c#, .net, file-extension, getfiles, filepattern

I am using the following line to return specific files...

```
FileInfo file in nodeDirInfo.GetFiles("*.sbs", option)
```

But there are other files in the directory with the extension `.sbsar`, and it is getting them, too. How can I differentiate between `.sbs` and `.sbsar` in the search pattern?

Comment: You cannot (at least with GetFiles/GetDirectories). This is a "limitation" of the search pattern. You should iterate through the results and filter manually the ones you want.

Comment: also take a look at this:    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, filtered using file extension.

```
  FileInfo[] files = nodeDirInfo.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).
            Where(f=>f.Extension==".sbs").ToArray<FileInfo>();
```

Answer (score 9):

The issue you're experiencing is a [limitation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the search pattern, in the Win32 API.

> A searchPattern with a file extension (for example *.txt) of exactly
>   three characters returns files having an extension of three or more
>   characters, where the first three characters match the file extension
>   specified in the searchPattern.

My solution is to manually filter the results, using Linq:

```
nodeDirInfo.GetFiles("*.sbs", option).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".sbs"),
    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: You don't account for letter case here.

Answer (score 6):

That's the behaviour of the Win32 API (`FindFirstFile`) that is underneath `GetFiles()` being reflected on to you.

You'll need to do your own filtering if you must use `GetFiles()`. For instance:

```
GetFiles("*", searchOption).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".sbs", 
    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Or more efficiently:

```
EnumerateFiles("*", searchOption).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".sbs", 
    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Note that I use `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` to deal with the fact that Windows file names are case-insensitive.

If performance is an issue, that is if the search has to process directories with large numbers of files, then it is more efficient to perform the filtering twice: once in the call to `GetFiles` or `EnumerateFiles`, and once to clean up the unwanted file names. For example:

```
GetFiles("*.sbs", searchOption).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".sbs", 
    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
EnumerateFiles("*.sbs", searchOption).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".sbs", 
    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: @Joey That just feels a little dirty to me, duplicating the filter. But perhaps it would have a perf implication. If not then I'd rather have just the one filter.

Comment: It's faster, though ;-) In my small test here (running over our complete source folder, searching for `*.cpp`) it's about 10–25 % faster to specify the filter in `GetFiles` too. `EnumerateFiles` is slightly slower, but probably uses much less memory, especially for large result sets.

Comment: @Joey Yes, I think that's reasonable. I guess it comes down to a balance between perf and purity! I've covered this in the answer now.

Comment: Oh, and I guess `.EndsWith(".sbs", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` would be a better option that's also resistant to culture, as the file system ignores the culture for its case-insensitivity.

Comment: @Joey Thanks. Showing my ignorance with `ToLower()`!

Answer (score 1):

Its mentioned in [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> When using the asterisk wildcard character in a searchPattern,a
>   searchPattern with a file extension of exactly three characters
>   returns files having an extension of three or more characters.When
>   using the question mark wildcard character, this method returns only
>   files that match the specified file extension.

Comment: It would be marvellous if this would be true. Unfortunately, it is not and and here comes a new episode of the poor descriptions of searchPattern in MSDN :) I felt curious and did some tests and here come my conclusions...

Comment: @varocarbas indeed..wonder where to use `?`.OP can use `*a?.sbs`..Though that would require `a` to be somewhere in the file name

Comment: `nodeDirInfo.GetFiles("5?.txt");` returns any file with just .txt (not .txtwhatever) containing two characters in the name, one of them being a 5. `nodeDirInfo.GetFiles("?.txt");` Returns any .txt file with just one character in its name (not including .txtwhatever). You can get only *.txt by using a `????.txt` approach if you know the maximum length of the file names you are looking for (??.txt retuns all the files with 1 or 2 characters in its name; ???.txt all the ones with 1,2 and 3, etc.).

Comment: this was the answer I was hoping would work. But '?.sbs' returned nothing and '*?.sbs" returned all files with 'sbs' in the extension. The only thing these file names have in common is the extension. I imagine that would be the case with many such searches. I agree with varocarbas, the docs are not clear.